# Generate realiable cache key for file

Tags: file, server, operating-system, filesystems

Is there a fast and reliable way to generate a key for a generic file, to serve as cache key to limit unnecessary downloads of big files? (Client retains a copy and a cache key, and the next time requesting the resources delivers the cache key. The server response with 302 - Not modified, if server has same cache key and therefore file is assumed to be unchanged).

I don't have full control over the modifications of the file to generate a key every time the file is changed.

If there is no generally guaranteed way, does it change when considering gzipped files on Windows? Are by any change the first n bits of compression distributed in a way, to assume uniqueness? (Similar to how people rely on on GUID/UUIDs without considering collisions).